# I can't call PATCH method using Pug, Mongoose and Express.js

Tags: mongodb, rest, express, mongoose, pug

I am new to code and I apologize in advance for all my noob mistakes.

I'm trying to set a new color to an existing object stored in MongoDB using the PATCH method in the browser, but I don't understand why its not working while the GET and POST methods are working.

I have to mention that the PATCH method works in Postman.

The code in my pug file:

```
        form(action=`/posts/changeColor` + id, method="patch")
            label Enter variable color:
                    input(type="text", name="color")
            button(type="Submit") Submit
```

And the code in express:

```
    router.patch('/posts/changeColor/:id', async(req, res)=>{
        try{
            const test = await products.updateOne({_id: req.params.id},{$set:{productColor: req.body.color}});
            res.json(test);
        }catch(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get after pressing the "Submit" button

```
    Cannot GET posts/changeColor/62723c3ed31baa41d5e9b0e1
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML forms can not initiate `PATCH` HTTP requests.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method